# How to convert Enumeration to Seq/List in scala?

Tags: scala, enumeration

I'm writing a servlet, and need to get all parameters from the request. I found `request.getParameterNames` returns a `java.util.Enumeration`, so I have to write code as:

```
val names = request.getParameterNames
while(names.hasMoreElements) {
    val name = names.nextElement
}
```

I wanna know is there any way to convert a `Enumeration` to a `Seq/List`, then I can use the `map` method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Use JavaConverters**

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5184386/133106

**Use a wrapper Iterator**

You could build up a wrapper:

```
val nameIterator = new Iterator[SomeType] { def hasNext = names.hasMoreElements; def next = names.nextElement }
```

**Use JavaConversions wrapper**

```
val nameIterator = new scala.collection.JavaConversions.JEnumerationWrapper(names)
```

**Using JavaConversions implicits**

If you import

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

you can do it implicitly (and you’ll also get implicit conversions for other Java collecitons)

```
request.getParameterNames.map(println)
```

**Use Iterator.continually**

You might be tempted to build an iterator using `Iterator.continually` like an earlier version of this answer proposed:

```
val nameIterator = Iterator.continually((names, names.nextElement)).takeWhile(_._1.hasMoreElements).map(_._2)
```

but it's incorrect as the last element of the enumerator will be discarded.
The reason is that the `hasMoreElement` call in the `takeWhile` is executed after calling `nextElement` in the `continually`, thus discarding the last value.

Comment: I think the first code contains a bug: it doesn't return the very last element. To get it you should do something like `val nameIterator = Iterator.continually((names.hasMoreElements, names)).takeWhile(_._1).map(_._2.nextElement)`

Comment: Note that `JavaConversions` is deprecated. See Kevin Wright's answer.

Answer (score 32):

Current best practice (since 2.8.1) is to use `scala.collection.JavaConverters`

- [Scaladoc here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html)

This class differs from `JavaConversions` slightly, in that the conversions are not fully automatic, giving you more control *(this is a good thing)*:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val names = ...
val nameIterator = names.asScala
```

Using this mechanism, you'll get appropriate and type-safe conversions for most collection types via the `asScala/asJava` methods.

Comment: `asScala` didn't work for me for some reason. I used `enumerationAsScalaIterator(enumeration)`.

Comment: @Mygod did you do the `import`? You need it in order to get the implicits.

Comment: Looks to now need `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

Comment: scala.collection.JavaConverters$' is deprecated 
Symbol JavaConverters is deprecated. Use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` instead

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with any of the other answers but I had to add a type cast to get this to compile in Scala 2.9.2 and Java 7.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
...
val names=request.getParameterNames.asInstanceOf[java.util.Enumeration[String]].toSet
```

Answer (score 1):

A comment on Debilski's answer that the Iterator.continually approach is wrong because it misses the last entry. Here's my test:

```
val list = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
list.add("hello")
list.add("world")
val en = java.util.Collections.enumeration(list)
val names = Iterator.continually((en, en.nextElement)).takeWhile(_._1.hasMoreElements).map(_._2)
    .foreach { name => println("name=" + name) }
```

Output is

```
name=hello
```

The second item (name=world) is missing!

I got this to work by using JavaConversions.enumerationAsScalaIterator as mentioned by others.

Note I don't have enough rep to comment on Debilski's post directly.