# How to covert Scala Seq to Java Enumeration

Tags: java, scala, enumeration

I want to convert a scala `Seq` to Java `java.util.Enumeration` any tips?

Comment: Why? What do you need an `Enumeration` for?

Comment: What did you try or find already? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184386/2308683

Comment: can you give a few more details? it seems an odd use case. Maybe you have a List of Strings and you want to convert each to one of the possible Enumeration values?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 `java.util.Enumeration` has nothing to do with enums. It's a pre-Java 1.2 version of `java.util.Iterator`.

Comment: The issue is I'm using a library that needs an Enumeration as argument to functions. but I have a Set in Scala. The Solution was to use `asEnumeration(someSet)` in JavaConvertors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is interested in the answer:

By importing `scala.collection.JavaConversions` I could use `asJavaEnumeration[A](i: Iterator[A]): Enumeration[A]` to do the job.

Comment: Is there any way to combine 2 Enumeration of same class?

Answer (score 0):

`Enumeration` is basically an *outdated* thing. It is one of those concepts that were introduced with Java 1.0, but that nobody would / should be using any more nowadays.

In 2017, you use **collections**. In other words: if at all, you turn your `Seq` into a `List`. You can read about how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737631/convert-from-scala-collection-seqstring-to-java-util-liststring-in-java-code).